# C++ How check characters in real time with _getch()

Tags: c++, input, char, enter, getch

i need in my loop get character in realtime and check it by conditions. If user press whatever except enter, program works fine. Can anyone help me ? thanks !

```
   while (read != '\n')
            {
                cout << "Enter character:\n";
                read = _getwch();
                if (read == '\n') {
                    cout << "You pressed : ENTER\n";
                }
                else {
                    cout << "Your character is: \"" << read << "\"\n\n";
                    read = '\0';
                }
            }
```

Comment: And what exactly happens when you press ENTER?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## include

using namespace std;

int main()

{

```
cout << "Press the ENTER key";

if (cin.get() == '\n')

{
       cout << "Good job.\n";
}
else
{
       cout << "I meant ONLY the ENTER key... Oh well.\n";
}
```

return 0;

}

This code will help in detecting the ENTER key when pressed.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: This code detecting characters afters ENTER press ... but i need check char after pressed any button ... for example .. press 'f' and console print 'f' ... and when i press enter console print "enter" and program shut down